# Custom login and register form in web2py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, web2py-modules

I am using

```
    form1= auth.login()
    form2= auth.register()
```

to generate the login and register forms in web2py, but now i want to delete some of the fields from these forms, how can i modify these predefined forms and add email verification in register form?
I tried defining new forms, but then i don’t want to loose functionality provided by predefined forms.

Comment: Check here: http://nasko7.blogspot.com/2011/09/web2py-tips-change-upload-folder.html and the manual http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#Customizing-Auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before:

```
 form1 = SQLFORM(....)
```

You can do

```
 db.auth_user.fieldname.writable = db.auth_user.fieldname.readable = False
```

You can also defined your own:

```
 db.define_table('auth_user', ....)
```

before you auth.define_tables() and your won table will be used.

Comment: I added auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = [ Field('organization', 'reference organization', widget=SQLFORM.widgets.autocomplete(request, db.organization.o_name, id_field=db.organization.id), label = 'Organization')] to get an extra field that would insert id of organization in ma auth_user.organization field and name on organizatio.o_name field but it is not working. any idea why